# TextField Border not showing in iphone below 6 Devices

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield

[image]

I have create bottom border of textfields it is showing on all devices from 6 and above but on below 6 it is not showing ..it is showing empty placeholder I have tested on 5s

I am using this code

```
func designTextfields(){

    let border = CALayer()
    let width = CGFloat(2.0)
    border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: emailField.frame.size.height - width, width:  emailField.frame.size.width, height: emailField.frame.size.height)

    border.borderWidth = width
    emailField.layer.addSublayer(border)
    emailField.layer.masksToBounds = true


    let border1 = CALayer()
    let width1 = CGFloat(2.0)
    border1.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    border1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: passField.frame.size.height - width1, width:  passField.frame.size.width, height: passField.frame.size.height)

    border1.borderWidth = width1
    passField.layer.addSublayer(border1)
    passField.layer.masksToBounds = true

}
```

Comment: are you facing this issue on simulator or actual device? Also where are you calling this method `designTextfields`??

Comment: You can use the view debugger in Xcode to inspect the view hierarchy and see whats going wrong.

Comment: is you xib/storyboard in iPhone5 size ?

Comment: try checking on real device or zoom in your simulator screen